# A* Search in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I just implemented a version of A* search in JavaScript for educational purposes. I'd really love it if you could take a look and tell me how to improve my code.

The `grid` passed in is just a multidimensional array (2-D array) where each slot in the inner array is an object with property `weight`.

The point of this function is to build an "algorithm visualizer", where I have all the nodes that were visited by A* (`visited`) and all the nodes that A* eventually selected to be part of the shortest path (`path`). I later take this and display this to the user with my UI logic.

In terms of the heuristic, I use Euclidean Distance.

```
import PriorityQueue from "./data structures/priorityqueue";

export default function astar(grid, startNode, endNode) {
  function isValid(r, c) {
    if (r < 0 || c < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (r < grid.length && c < grid[r].length) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function calculateHeuristic(r, c) {
    let row = (endNode[0] - r) ** 2;
    let col = (endNode[1] - c) ** 2;
    return (row + col) ** (1 / 2);
  }

  let dist = [], // represents distances from start to node
    visited = [], // list of all the nodes A* visits
    ordering = []; // final ordering

  for (let r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
    let row = [],
      orderingRow = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
      row.push(Number.MAX_VALUE);
      orderingRow.push(null);
    }
    dist.push(row);
    ordering.push(orderingRow);
  }
  let d = 0;
  let pqueue = new PriorityQueue();
  let priority = calculateHeuristic(startNode[0], startNode[0]) + d;
  pqueue.enqueue([startNode[0], startNode[1], startNode, d], priority);
  let cur,
    neighbors = [
      [1, 0],
      [-1, 0],
      [0, 1],
      [0, -1]
    ];

  while (!pqueue.isEmpty()) {
    cur = pqueue.dequeue();
    let r = cur.element[0],
      c = cur.element[1],
      origin = cur.element[2],
      d = cur.element[3];

    visited.push([r, c]);

    if (dist[r][c] <= d) {
      continue;
    }

    ordering[r][c] = origin;
    dist[r][c] = d;

    if (r === endNode[0] && c === endNode[1]) {
      break;
    }

    for (let n of neighbors) {
      let rr = r + n[0];
      let cc = c + n[1];
      if (!isValid(rr, cc)) {
        continue;
      }
      let dd = d + grid[rr][cc].weight;
      if (dd < dist[rr][cc]) {
        priority = dd + calculateHeuristic(rr, cc);
        pqueue.enqueue([rr, cc, [r, c], dd], priority);
      }
    }
  }

  let path = [endNode];

  let r = endNode[0],
    c = endNode[1];

  while (r !== startNode[0] || c !== startNode[1]) {
    path.push(ordering[r][c]);
    [r, c] = ordering[r][c];
  }
  path.reverse();
  return { visited, path };
}
```

Thank you for reading and I look forward to your critiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 3 parallel 2D arrays in javascript for simple data is a bit overkill. Put those in a single 2D array or you can fold it into the grid's nodes.

If you want step by step visualization then you'll need to break up your function into sections: `init`, `step` and `finalize`.

`init` is everything before the main while loop.

`step` is the while loop body

`finalize` is only triggered when the loop otherwise breaks or exits.

Whether you group all the data it needs (like pqueue, dist, etc.) into an object that gets passed in or become globals doesn't really matter when it's for educational reasons. But if they are in a single object then it's easier for the visualizer to get that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I agree that a single 2D array makes a lot more sense. I'll be making those changes.

Sorry, for the visualizer, that's meant to be in React (so a completely different class). I just wrote this as a class in a separate folder to separate the UI logic from the not-UI logic. I implement a function called "paintNodes" in my React Component that takes in the list and then adds a Timeout and prints out the nodes. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SomyaAgrawal I believe that showing the algorithm split up instead as a monolith is wothwhile though. Especially as it teaches that you don't need to make the algorithm spit out the result immediately but can instead let it work in timeslices without needing threads

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the suggestion.

I will work on implementing that in the future.